# Load Local Images from Local XML

Tags: android

I am loading a XML Parsing files and getting its data on a listview. I want to know is there any way to load images from Local SD Card or application instead of loading it from the Internet URL.

XML file i have like this :-

```
<id>4</id>
<title>Lesson</title>
<artist>English</artist>
<duration>4:23</duration>
<thumb_url>https://abc.com/apple.png</thumb_url>
```

Want it to change like this :-

```
<id>4</id>
<title>Lesson</title>
<artist>English</artist>
<duration>4:23</duration>
<thumb_url>R.id.apple</thumb_url>
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what (or why) you're asking. The Android documentation has plenty of example of using either 'raw' images or 'drawable' resources.

Comment: I believe the way your are described is not possible, since `R.id.apple` will be a constant. Unless you use reflection to retrieve the constant value from the `<thumb_url>` tag, then all you have to do is use the `Resource` class to load the image.